# Floating paragraphs

Tags: css

I have an div with certain size , and it image and two paragraphs.

All of them have set float to left

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.one {
  float: left;
}
.two {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://img.timeinc.net/time/daily/2010/1001/360_br10q_0208.jpg" alt="">
  <p class="one">one</p>
  <p class="two">two</p>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o1xorbgu/)

What i want to achieve , is to have the paragraphs be under each other , while still having float left or achieving same result as with float , is it possible? If so , how can  i achieve so?

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/o1xorbgu/1/)

```css
div {
  width: 115px;
  float: left;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://img.timeinc.net/time/daily/2010/1001/360_br10q_0208.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
</div>
```

You could float the two parent containers. For the paragraphs, you don't need to float them!

Hope it will give you some idea

Answer (score 0):

If you want images and paragraphs to stack below each other one by one then remove the CSS `float:left;` from `.one` `.two` and `img`. DIV tags are block elements and would naturally flow down the page. You are floating them which would cause them to be displayed side by side.

Or

If I may have misunderstood the question and you want something like below code then put one and two inside a div and remove float from them. So when you place them inside a div they get natural flow of div i.e. `display:block;`

```css
div{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
img{
  float:left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.para{
 
}
.one{
}
.two{
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="http://img.timeinc.net/time/daily/2010/1001/360_br10q_0208.jpg" alt="">
<div class="para">


  <p class="one">one</p>
  <p class="two">two</p>
  </div>d
</div>
```

Comment: was this helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Assign `clear: left` to `.one` and `.two`:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.one {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.two {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://img.timeinc.net/time/daily/2010/1001/360_br10q_0208.jpg" alt="">
  <p class="one">one</p>
  <p class="two">two</p>
</div>
```